# Why am I receiving phantom Jobs alerts after unsubscribing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I've removed my job alerts a couple months ago, yet I'm still receiving alerts.
I've tried changing my preferences, but they don't seem to stick.

Comment: Can you display a screen shot of your "alert settings" within your jobs tab?

Comment: Maybe I have 2 accounts, but the email link to unsubscribe is taking me to the wrong account? Does that make sense?

Comment: Let me throw this in for kicks. When I click on my Stack Exchange inbox in the browser and choose any email that is from October or earlier, I get a page not found message. http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages/1633859

Comment: There were two accounts on the Talent (ex-Careers) side indeed, we merged them together. Can you verify your settings, and if you get another stray email, ping me?

Comment: I can see those emails now and my job settings look ok. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Can you double check your "Jobs Emails" settings on [the preferences page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current)? It seems that there are several enabled for you. Make sure to click "Save job board settings".

Here's how mine looks for example:

[image: Jobs Emails]

Comment: I know I've disabled these email options, seems like it doesn't stick. Now I can't find these settings. I have to say, the UI makes it difficult to quickly find settings.

Comment: @ArtMetz Thanks for the update, I'm investigating this today.